# Regular expression with a Levensthein distance

Tags: regex

I want to find an agglomeration of some particular keywords within a bigger text, the max occurrence of the any of the colors. It does not matter which color, even if it's the same one repeated many times.

The regular expression that I'm using is for example for a group of four colors:

```
(white|black|green|red|pink|violet|blue|orange|violet|pink).{1,100}(white|black|green|red|pink|violet|blue|orange|violet|pink).{1,100}(white|black|green|red|pink|violet|blue|orange|violet|pink).{1,100}(white|black|green|red|pink|violet|blue|orange|violet|pink).{1,100}
```

I would need to allow some spelling mistakes e.g. typos in any of the colors e.g. vioet or gren however I want to limit these typos to only a few. I was thinking to apply a Levensthein distance for any of the colors and I thought of the regex python library with approximate fuzzy matching (https://pypi.org/project/regex/) since it has a way to define the limit of the Levensthein distance.

I tried `print(regex.search(r'(black|white|green).{1,300}(black|white|green){e<=4}', 'green wrhite'))`
and this works.
However if I try

```
print(regex.search(r'(black|white|green).{1,300}(black|white|green){e<=4}', 'gren white'))
```

I get a result None. Even though from green to gren it's just one additional character.

The above is just an example to show you that I tried. I also tried the fuzzywuzzy python library and couldn't make it work.

Could you please help me find a way to search an agglomeration of words and also allowing for some typos.
The above are just some examples, I will need to search for other keywords agglomeration and in other languages as well other than English.
I started in python but I could use another programming language if python is not offering a solution. What I read somewhere is that the problem with the above code is due to backtracking... and that there may not be a solution to it. I will define the Levensthein distance based on the keywords searched e.g. if I'm searching for short words then I would set a low distance, if I search for longer words e.g. 'Incomprehensibilities' then I would set the distance to a higher value. The setting of the distance I can do it manually it's not a problem.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code works since it is applying the Levensthein distance to both groups, the first and the second group.

```
print(regex.search(r'(black|white|green){e<=1}.{1,300}(black|white|green){e<=1}', 'gren white'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Think about what your expression means:

1. You require either `black` or `white` or `green` literally
2. ... then 1-300 characters greedily
3. ... then the colours with some errors allowed

This won't match in `gren white` as you did not make the first colour match optional. However `print(regex.search(r'(?:green){e<=4}', 'gren white'))` will produce a result.

You'd need to present more input strings but I assume that it would be easier to use [**`nltk`**](https://www.nltk.org/) over regular expressions.

---

That being said, maybe this gets you started:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from Levenshtein import distance

data = """
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

green red gren rod
Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   
green

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   

Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer
"""

for word in word_tokenize(data):
    if distance(word, "green") <= 2:
        print(word)
```

Will yield

```
green
gren
green
```

Comment: I would start from few characters of the now 300 any character, for example 10, but many repetitions of the colour groups e.g. let's say 10 repetitions. And then since it is very unlikely to find something I start gradually to decrease the number of groups and increase the distance between the groups this is why I sometimes reach 300 characters. However this is less relevant in my view as if 300 by 10 the same result occurs. Based on your answer I believe that this should work: `print(regex.search(r'(black|white|green){e<=1}.{1,300}(black|white|green){e<=1}', 'gren white'))` . Thank you very m